# Grocery List in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm just trying to make my life easier and make a shiny app where I can select certain recipes I always make. My recipes are stored as objects (ChickenPotPie) and these objects are character lists of ingredients (i.e. "chicken","pie crust","broccoli"). I have a nice script that already can take my recipe lists and spit out a data frame with the item names and quantities. However, I want to make something that my husband will be able to use (he does not know any R), and I think creating a shiny app might be good for that.

This is very stupid question but I am very novice to shiny and wondering if anyone has any advice for resources where I could make a very simple app where I can check boxes with which recipes (objects) I am planning on making, and it will just print the objects (ie. character lists) out into a data frame?

Example code for what I've created so far is below..

```
#### RECIPE MASTER LIST ########

"The staples" <- c("milk", "12 eggs", "cheddar cheese", "sparkling water", "butter", "flour")
"Honey Mustard Dijon Chicken" <- c("1 lb chicken breast", "1 lb chicken breast", "panko crumbs", "brussel sprouts","shallot","shallot","fresh thyme")
"Sheet pan gnocchi" <- c("32 oz gnocchi","parmesan cheese","onion","cherry tomatoes","arugulua")
"Sheet pan chicken meatballs" <- c("panko","6 oz feta","egg", "minced garlic","ground meat/vegan meat", "1 pint cherry tomatoes", "1 can chickpeas")
# https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/sheet-pan-chicken-meatballs-with-tomatoes-and-chickpeas


MasterList <- names(.GlobalEnv)

###### WHAT ARE YOU MAKING THIS WEEK?! #########

# What are my options?
print(MasterList)

# Of this, what do I want to include? 
currentlist <- c(`Honey Mustard Dijon Chicken`, `The staples`,`Sheet pan gnocchi`)



#### Display List #####
CurrentGroceries<-as.data.frame(table(currentlist))
colnames(CurrentGroceries) <- c("Item","Quantity")

View(CurrentGroceries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this.

First we put all of the recipes inside a list object and then we proceed to create one selectInput to choose from the available recipes. Finally subset the `recipes` list using the value of the selectInput and display it inside a table.

App:

```
#### RECIPE MASTER LIST ########
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

recipes <- list(
  "The staples" = c(
    "milk", "12 eggs", "cheddar cheese", "sparkling water", "butter", "flour"
  ),
  "Honey Mustard Dijon Chicken" = c(
    "1 lb chicken breast", "1 lb chicken breast", "panko crumbs",
    "brussel sprouts", "shallot", "shallot", "fresh thyme"
  ),
  "Sheet pan gnocchi" = c(
    "32 oz gnocchi", "parmesan cheese", "onion", "cherry tomatoes", "arugulua"
  ),
  "Sheet pan chicken meatballs" = c(
    "panko", "6 oz feta", "egg", "minced garlic", "ground meat/vegan meat",
    "1 pint cherry tomatoes", "1 can chickpeas"
  )
)

# https://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/sheet-pan-chicken-meatballs-with-tomatoes-and-chickpeas

MasterList <- names(recipes)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("What Are You Making This Week?"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(
        "masterclass",
        "What are my options?",
        choices  = MasterList,
        multiple = TRUE
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(tableOutput("ingredients"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  current_groceries <- eventReactive(input$masterclass, {
    recipes[input$masterclass] %>%
      purrr::reduce(c) %>%
      table() %>%
      as.data.frame() %>%
      purrr::set_names(c("Item", "Quantity"))
  })

  output$ingredients <- renderTable({
    current_groceries()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Wow, this is perfect, thank you so much!! This is also helping me a lot in learning some of the basics of shiny